# Display images vertically until end of page, then continue horizontally within 100% height responsive div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

[image]

I am using the following code which displays images vertically within a div that has 100% height and a auto width. I want the images to be displayed vertically until the end of the page and then start displaying horizontally. I want the content div width to be automated based on how many images are displayed but always have the 100% height. At the moment the images are displayed vertically until the page ends and then the rest of the images are hidden in the overflow.

```
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: table;
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#thumbnailgrid {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

#thumbnailgrid img {
    width: auto;
    height: 24%;
}
```

Comment: post relevant html please!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I came up to, you might want to modify it a bit to fit your needs because this one doesn't keep track of margins or paddings, but it should help you solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/crbmL7sb/4/

To see it working try resizing the result window and clicking on "Run" again. You might want to add a window resize event listener as well.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="single">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=A1" alt="placeholder" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=A2" alt="placeholder" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=A3" alt="placeholder" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=A4" alt="placeholder" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=A5" alt="placeholder" />
    </div>
    <div class="single">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=B1" alt="placeholder" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=B2" alt="placeholder" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=B3" alt="placeholder" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=B4" alt="placeholder" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=B5" alt="placeholder" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
var CL = function( vals ) {
    columns = vals.columns;
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    this.init = function() {
        this.createColumns();
        this.setBodyWidth();
    }

    this.createColumns = function() {
        //loop through all the big columns
        for(var i=0, l=columns.length; i < l; i++) {
            images = $(columns[i]).find("img"); //get all the images in this column
            columnHeight = 0; //set a flag to store the column height
            var newDiv = $("<div />").addClass("inner"); //create an inner div inside the column
            for (var p=0, n=images.length; p < n; p++) { //loop through all the images in this column
                columnHeight += $(images[p]).height(); //add the height of the current image to the column height flag
                if (columnHeight >= wHeight) { //compare the column height with the window height, if there's NOT enough room for the new image
                    newDiv.appendTo($(columns[i])); //append this column to the big parent div
                    var newDiv = $("<div />").addClass("inner"); //create a new column
                    columnHeight = $(images[p]).height(); //reset the column height flag
                }
                $(images[p]).appendTo(newDiv); //add the image to the current column
            }
            // THIS IS THE LINE I FORGOT
            newDiv.appendTo($(columns[i]));
        }
    }

    this.setBodyWidth = function() {
        //when moving the images in the appropriate divs is done
        var totWidth = 0;
        $(".inner").each(function() {
           totWidth += $(this).width(); //get the width of all the content
        }) //and set it to the main wrapper to create the horizontal scrollbar
        vals.wrapper.css({
            width: totWidth
        })
    }

    this.init();
}


//You need to somehow preload the images, or this will not work. Maybe add an overlay to cover the page while the images are being loaded and then fade it out. A simple window load even (like I commented out below) should work, but it appears to be broken on jsfiddle.
//$(window).load(function() {
    var cl = new CL({
        columns: $(".single"),
        wrapper: $(".wrapper")
    });
//});
```

And a little bit of CSS

```
img {
    display: block;
}

.inner {
    float: left;
}

img {
    border: 4px solid white;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works really well except for that images are deleted if they can't fit in the window. 

In your example, A5 and B5 are not displayed on my screen (27-inch 2560 x 1440).

Any ideas on how to get all images visible regardless of what screen size it is?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice, I'll fix it and let you know

Comment: Fixed, can you check it? I marked the mistake with the comment //THIS IS THE LINE I FORGOT